# Team Foundation (TFS 2010) Folder Cloaking - Server Side Alternative?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, tfs

I have a website project that is consuming user controls from another shared project. I am using a build event to copy the *.ascx files over from the source user control project.

I don't want the ascx files to be checked into TFS source control from the consuming project, only the source project. Is there a way to keep TFS from trying to check in files from a specific folder other then cloaking?

My issue with cloaking is that it's a client side function, which means every developer who takes down the project would have to manually cloak the folder or folders in question themselves. I'd like to be able to setup the solution in such a way as a developer could take the project down from source control without having to manually configure it to accommodate my separate project for shared user controls.

There is an article here: http://devio.wordpress.com/2009/11/05/shared-aspx-and-ascx-files-in-visual-studio-and-tfs/ that seems to address this issue but I think they're setup is different then mine in that I am using a website project and not a web application project. Being that I have no .csproj file there's no way to include or exclude files from my project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the TFS Power Tools (if you haven't already) http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f, under Team Members > General Settings, you can setup a Worspace Template to cloak as needed.

Not played with it myself, but looks to be the functionality that you need.

Comment: Cool, that looks like it could be real useful thank you. I'll check that out and get back to the thread.

Comment: I ended up biting the bullet and converting my project from a website project to a web application project which allowed me to to address my issue without the need for TFS power tools, either with a check in policy or a Workspace template. Losing dynamic compilation was a tough move but I really needed the build events, web.config transformations and Application Settings functionality that's only available for WAP project types.

Comment: @BrooklynDev: Just curious, why did you find the loss of dynamic compilation difficult?